# How to validate non administrator user using c#?

Tags: c#, .net, principalcontext

I have created a local user. (Ex: mymachine\user1). 
I do not want to add this user to administrator group.

I have used following c# code to validate my local account:

```
PrincipalContext contextmachine = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Machine);    
valid = contextmachine.ValidateCredentials(accountname, password);
```

But it is giving exception as:

> Logon failure: the user has not been granted the requested logon type
>   at this computer.

please help me if I m doing it in a right way.

Comment: Or anyone can suggest me any alternative to principal context

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
PrincipalContext contextmachine = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Machine);
valid = contextmachine.ValidateCredentials(accountname, password);

UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, IdentityType.SamAccountName, userId);  
foreach (Principal p in usr.GetAuthorizationGroups())
{
    if (p.ToString() == "Administrators")
    {
        result = true;
    }
}
```